# MySQL/MariaDB - LIMIT joined query result while not losing any primary ID

Tags: mysql, join, distinct, limit, mariadb

I know how to limit a query results with `LIMIT a,b`  but what if I want to `LIMIT` query that was created with `JOIN`s which has multiple rows of one primary ID while keeping at least one row per ID?

**Let me explain more...***

I have table of posts, then there is a table of categories.

One post, however, can be in more categories.

When I do query for posts I also want to query for their categories at the same time...

...the thing is I only need 1 category max. per 1 post result (I don't care which one)

**Current (*exemplary*) results**

```
ID   | title       | content | category_ID | category_name
1    | First Post  | ....... |   2         | Boring Articles
1    | First Post  | ....... |   5         | Interesting Articles
1    | First Post  | ....... |   1         | Mojo Tips
2    | Second Post | ....... |   5         | Interesting Articles
3    | Third Post  | ....... |   5         | Interesting Articles
3    | Third Post  | ....... |   4         | Fitness
4    | Fourth Post | ....... |   NULL      | NULL
```

**The desired (*exemplary*) results - *note that at least one row per post ID was kept!***

```
ID   | title       | content | category_ID | category_name
1    | First Post  | ....... |   2         | Boring Articles
2    | Second Post | ....... |   5         | Interesting Articles
3    | Third Post  | ....... |   5         | Interesting Articles
4    | Fourth Post | ....... |   NULL      | NULL
```

But if I would do just *something* like

```
SELECT * FROM posts
LEFT JOIN relationships USING(ID)
LEFT JOIN categories USING(category_ID)
LIMIT 0,4
```

This would happen (***loosing needed data*** - not 1 row per 1 ID anymore...):

```
ID   | title       | content | category_ID | category_name
1    | First Post  | ....... |   2         | Boring Articles
1    | First Post  | ....... |   5         | Interesting Articles
1    | First Post  | ....... |   1         | Mojo Tips
2    | Second Post | ....... |   5         | Interesting Articles
```

PS: I would like to know how to solve this in MySQL/MariaDB and if there is a difference in doing this when using one or another - then what is the difference please? :)

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: What is unclear? I can't imagine why would you need create/insert statements when my question is about limiting existing results... And I did provide an example SQL query and results... On top of all my question is more of general question than a DB-specific one...

Comment: A result set without a data set is like a stick without a lollipop. No fun at all. Not "caring which one" is sometimes indicative of poor design.

Comment: @Strawberry I disagree when you have a stick you still know it's a stick and still now how to break it in half :) I agree that "not carring which one" CAN indicate poor design, but in this particular case it is opposite (in the particular final usage :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses a subquery:

```
SELECT p.*,
       (SELECT c.category_name
        FROM relationships r JOIN
             categories c
             USING (category_ID)
       WHERE r.id = p.id
       LIMIT 1
      ) as category_name
FROM posts p
LIMIT 0, 4;
```

Note:  You would normally have an `ORDER BY` when using `LIMIT`.

Another method uses `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT p.*, c.*
FROM posts p LEFT JOIN
     relationships r
     USING (ID) LEFT JOIN
     categories c
     USING (category_ID)
GROUP BY p.id
LIMIT 0, 4;
```

I am not a fan of using `GROUP BY` like this, but it is a valid MySQL extension.

Comment: Well, you're using the term 'valid' in a very particular way.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff - one additional question - do you know which one is faster (considering large data, otherwise I would test it myself :) )

Comment: @jave.web . . . The first should be faster.  The `group by` in the second would slow things down a lot.  Of course, you can test this, but that is my expectation.

Comment: @GordonLinoff and why would group by slow things down? :) (in comparsion to the latter one)

Comment: @jave.web . . . MySQL uses a sort for `group by`, and this grows as O(n log n).  That means that has the data gets larger, the sort takes longer and longer.  By contrast, the first method should find a matching category simply by looking up a value in a couple of indexes.  So, the first query should be faster than the `group by`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  - Ah, so it sorts the whole group by before limiting it... ? One would thought it would just make "picks" by indexes and do this just 4 times :) Thank you for your throughout explanation :)